# DataGridView con 20.000 registros, solución para mejorar performance?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

Tengo un `DataGridView`, que cuenta con poco más de 20.000 registros.

Al cargar el formulario tengo una demora de 6/7 segundos hasta que se llena el `DataGridView`.

Probé trabajar con un `BackgroundWork`, y mientras, mostrar un gif animado para disimular la demora. Tuve algunos problemas al aplicar esto ya que no sabía muy bien cómo ejecutar la función `Fill` dentro del `BackgroundWork`. De todas maneras, quisiera encontrar alguna solución para disminuir la demora.

También probé trabajar con el `DataGridView` en `VirtualMode`, pero creo que tampoco me sirve, ya que todos los registros son necesarios, y tengo entendido que la idea de trabajar en `VirtualMode` es utilizar sólo los registros que sean necesarios para la aplicación.

A alguien se le ocurre alguna idea como para mejorar la performance y disminuir la demora?
La Base de Datos está en un archivo Access.

Les dejo el código que ejecuto al cargar el formulario:

```
Private Sub Detalle_Editar_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ArtículosDataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
    Me.ArtículosTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ArtículosDataSet.Artículos)

End Sub
```

Saludos!

**EDIT --**

Apliqué la propiedad `DoubleBuffered` a mi `DataGridView` y al formulario, pero no noto diferencia en el rendimiento. Dejo mi código actualizado:

```
Private Sub Detalle_Editar_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ArtículosDataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
    MakeGridViewDoubleBuffered(ArtículosDataGridView)
    Me.ArtículosTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ArtículosDataSet.Artículos)
End Sub

Public Sub MakeGridViewDoubleBuffered(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    Dim dgvType As Type = dgv.[GetType]()
    Dim pi As PropertyInfo = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    pi.SetValue(dgv, True, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, ¿porque cargas tanta data en el Grid?

Comment: Es una base de artículos para un sistema de facturación. El negocio cuenta con más de 20.000 artículos, entre los cuales tengo que ejecutar búsquedas por código y nombre para generar ventas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo depende de como queres acceder a los datos en **tiempo de ejecución** y que **experiencia** brindar al usuario.

Pasé por un caso similar y encontré la **solución en habilitar la propiedad `DoubleBuffered` del `DataGridView`**.

Dicha propiedad se encuentra, por ejemplo, en el `Form` y permite que trabaje con mejor rendimiento el control.

Pero, en las propiedades del DataGridView es probable que no la encuentres, por eso puedes habilitarlo mediante código.

Te copio la función que yo utilizo para habilitar dicha opción en mis controles DGV, que debes llamarla en el evento Load del formulario en cuestión y verás una mejora en la carga/muestra de los datos.

Primero colocar al inicio del formulario donde copiaremos el Procedimiento:

```
Imports System.Reflection

 Public Sub DoubleBufferedASD(dgv As DataGridView, setting As Boolean)
        Dim dgvType As Type = dgv.[GetType]()
        Dim pi As PropertyInfo = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, Nothing)
    End Sub
```

Y lo llamo asi:

```
   DoubleBufferedASD(dgArticulos, True)
```

**EDIT:**

Hay más **opciones** para responder a tu **pregunta**, tales como: **paginación**, o solucionar la carga con un `BackgroundWorker` (como has comentado), pero como el método    `Me.ArtículosTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ArtículosDataSet.Artículos)` esta en el UI principal deberas ejecutarlo desde el evento BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted.

Podemos hacer más extensa esta respuesta, con dichas opciones, para que queden una pregunta/respuesta ideal para alguien que le suceda algo similar.

Comment: Gracias por contestar! Dónde defino los tipos PropertyInfo y BindingFlags?

Comment: **Imports System.Reflection** Me olvidé de que definas esos tipos en el comienzo del formulario.

Comment: Ok, ya apliqué la propiedad, pero lamentablemente no noto que haya mejorado el rendimiento.. Ahora edito mi pregunta inicial así dejo mi código actualizado.

Comment: Comprendo, no olvides que hay un límite físico entre la carga de dicha información en memoria, la computadora en la que estás trabajando y como lo estás cargando. Es muy difícil hablar de aumentar notoriamente el rendimiento si hablamos de una matriz de 20,000 filas por X columnas (si traes más datos, por ejemplo en vez de solo Código & Descripción traes Código, Descripción, Stock, Precio, etc la matriz será mucho más grande).

Comment: La solución definitiva sino es paginar, lo que mejoraría muchisimo el rendimiento de tu programa ya que no traes 20,000 registros a memoria sino una X cantidad y luego vas paginándolo.

Comment: Entiendo, pero, cómo funcionaría la búsqueda por código y nombre en el DataGridView con un paginado?

Comment: Eso sería otra pregunta, y tendrá, otra respuesta. Si investigas un poco también podrías ayudarte. No tengo tu código, ergo, no puedo contestarte al aire. **Aproximadamente** me atrevo a decirte que no tienes necesidad de traer tanta información a memoria para filtrarla porque puedes filtrarla en el momento de buscarla y no traer 20.000 sino 100, 20, 5 o 10 según los resultados a tu consulta.

Comment: Bien, voy a investigar por ese lado entonces! Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Para que tengas una idea yo trabajo contra MySQL, con BackgroundWorkers y consultas que traen matrices de aproximadamente 30 columnas x n filas. De forma local y recibiendo un resultado de 40.000 registros a memoria estoy tardando algo de 9 segundos. No creo que sea mejorable el número ya que son muchos datos en memoria, pero no tengo la necesidad en la experiencia del usuario de reducir dicho tiempo. Para lo que vos necesitas, y si queres reducir ese tiempo, es necesario usar paginación.